# Get data from 3 datatables with and without filtering

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I got 3 data tables using below.

```
public virtual DataSet ExecuteDataset(IDbConnection connection, CommandType commandType, string commandText);
```

I want to get data from these 3 data tables. 
[image]

[image]

[image]

When no filters are applied I need data like below.
[image]

When filter [leave type is medical] is applied to main table I need like below.[image]

When filter [Name is John] is applied to profile table I need like below.
[image]

How can I achieve these results in C#? I used code mentioned above to get data with and without filters. As a result I am getting 3 separate datatables.  I use below code to join the datatables.

```
var ret = from p in mainReport.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
          join q in attachmentDetails.Tables[0].AsEnumerable() 
          on p.Field<string>("Req ID") equals q.Field<string>("Req ID") into comps
          from y in comps.DefaultIfEmpty()
          join r in associateDetails.Tables[0].AsEnumerable() 
          on p.Field<string>("ID") equals r.Field<string>("ID") into UP
          from r in UP.DefaultIfEmpty() 
          select new { p,y,r};
```

This query is returning proper data for no filter case. For filter case I am getting all rows in all tables. What is the issue with my query? Is there a better way to achieve needed results?

Comment: What is the "filter case" you are doing? This code looks good. Did a left join as needed and retrieved the data. Without the `Where` clause we can't help about the filtering problem

Comment: While querying DB table itself I am applying where/filter conditions. So I am getting datatables with filtered data. No issue with filters. When joining the filtered datatble I am not getting proper data. I guess it is due to left join. So I need to use some other LINQ query with inner join for filtered datatables I guess.